# TarArchiveInputStream doesn't seem to handle links

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons

Is there any way to extract hard links from a tar.gz file using java code? I've been trying to use org.apache.commons.compress.*, code found online, but linked files always end up with 0 bytes (and the wrong permissions) and I haven't found any examples or discussions regarding linked files. 
I'm a complete newbie and would appreciate any guidance in this matter.